# Unique Groups and Seatings for Game Tournament

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to develop a system to generate pairings for a multiplayer game tournament. It should be generic, to support tournaments of 10 players up to 500 (or more).

The tournament is played in multiple rounds, usually two or three. For each round, players are placed in groups of 5 (and some groups of 4 if the number of players doesn't add up to 5). In each group, a player is assigned a position, which also affects the outcome of the game.

### Constraints:

- Minimize repeated pairings (such as the social golfer problem).
- The sum of positions a player was placed in should be roughly the same (if a player seats as 1st, then 3rd, then 5th, the sum of positions is 8).
- Be able to add or remove players inbetween rounds. Sometimes, a player gets disqualified or has to leave early, and sometimes players arrive late and can only start playing on the 2nd round.
- If player A just sat before player B, they can never be positioned as A->B again, even if on different positions (this includes player A being 5th and player B being 1st)

I've managed to tackle the first and third constraint with a near-solver, generating permutations of players and mutating the permutations with a score function, in order to reach at least a local peak. But I don't see how to add the other constraints.

Comment: Could you show what you have done so far more concretely? For example with some math expressions?

Comment: @Divide1918 It's a brute solver, I'm not really good at expressing myself with maths.

- Create a matrix of zeros to represent each pair of players.
- Generate random permutations of players for the first round.
- Add 1 to each pair of players that played together on the first round.
- For subsequent rounds, generate random permutations of players, then use the squared number of the matrix as a score. Keep swapping players in order to reduce the total score of the system.

If a player enters (or leave) the tournament, just add (or remove) him from the matrix.